# On change of any checkbox inside a div trigger a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

Let's say there are multiple checkboxes inside a div (call it "startwars" ) i know how to check and trigger a function if state of checkbox is changed or clicked on all over the page by doing :

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    console.log("somethign is checked on the page")
});
```

but what if i want to limit that scope to a div and check if any of checkbox state is changed/clicked which are inside that a div,

I want to trigger a function if any of the checkbox is changed/clicked inside a div element with JQuery

Comment: $('#myDivId input[type=checkbox]') :-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

add a class or id to the div you want to limit scope of and use it in your selector in jQuery

```
<div class='limited'>
    <input type='checkbox' />
</div
```

JS

```
$('.limited input[type=checkbox]').change(function() { // while you're at it listen for change rather than click, this is in case something else modifies the checkbox
    console.log("something is checked on the page")
});
```

Comment: Veryhelp for the `.change` and `.click` difference you have explained, Nice!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by adding an id or class to the div you want the event to occur in like this: https://jsfiddle.net/oa9wj80x/10/

```
<div id="slct"">
<h1>
INSIDE
</h1>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox">
</div>
<div>
<h1>
OUTSIDE
</h1>
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
</div>
<script>
$('#slct input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){ 
alert("See it's working");
});
</script>
```